# Javascript $.POST directing to a folder

Tags: javascript

I have a code below which works fine. However, when I move the update.php from the root folder to a folder named "sql" and change the line to $.post("sql/update.php"); the script does not work. It appears that it can't access to the file. Does anyone know why?

```
<script>
    setInterval("update()", 10000);
    function update() { 
      $.post("update.php");
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. What does the HTTP response look like? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I have figured it out based on your suggestion. The browser tool indicates the script is executing so we know there is nothing wrong there. The problem is in the script ("update.php") where I didn't change the database connection from "sql/db.php" to "db.php" since "db.php" and "update.php" are located in the same folder. Luckily I still have some hairs left. I'm pulling my hairs out over this ridiculously simple issue. Thanks for your help, Quentin.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add slash

```
$.post("/sql/update.php");
```

Comment: I tried that also but it didn't work. This thing is driving me nut. It seems to be a simple thing but I couldn't figure it out why.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Дмитрий Алфёров. Problem solved!

Comment: @MasterJoe how?